# How to use multiple remote validation using jquery plugin on a single field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to use multiple remote validation on a single field using jquery validation plugin i was trying it but it was not forking.

Suppose i have a field email : abc@zmart.com, i have to check abc first if it is available in our db then show the message it is unavailable, and through second i have to check that whether zmart is in our database if it is then OK otherwise i have to display error message it is not registered.

```
$("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
                remote: "check_domain_email.php",
                remote: "check_first_email_name"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            username: "Username is required.",
            remote: "Email of this domain is not available.",
            remote: "Please use another name."
        }
    });
```

I have applied the above code but it is not working please help and give any suggestions of how it can be accomplished. Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot use the same rule twice on the same field and there is no point.  Simply adjust your server-side logic to handle everything at the same time.  It will be a better experience for your users as well.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if 2 remotes are supported.
However, you can do both the validation in one ajax call and return the custom error message in the response as in "username is already taken" or "email is already taken".

Please check it for reference.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method

The response is evaluated as JSON and must be true for valid elements, and can be any false, undefined or null for invalid elements, using the default message; or a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead" to display as the error message.

Comment: I will confirm that you cannot use the same rule twice on the same field.